# Manually Triggered Gitlab Job - User Credentials

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Job that can only be triggered manually.
When triggered, it generates a release version commit and tag.

I would like to be able to push that commit and tag to the current commit branch, and the push should be "by the user".

Is there any way to accomplish this? I dont want to use a token, because that loses the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont want to use a token, because that loses the user.

Using a token doesn't prevent you from using any particular git author. One option is just set the git config to use the email of the user that triggered the job. This is available in the [predefined environment variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL`.

Before writing the commit/tag, set the user email in the git config:

```bash
git config --local user.email "$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL"
```

GitLab uses the commit author email to associate commits with users. So if you do this, the commit and tag will be associated with the user who triggered the job and their portrait will show up in the UI for the commit.

You can also add the git `user.name` if you want with the variable `$GITLAB_USER_NAME` though this is not strictly necessary. You may also use a different name to help differentiate automated commits.

As a complete example (for branch pipelines, using a [project access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) stored as the variable `PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN`):

```bash
# set the user properties
git config --local user.email "$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL"
git config --local user.name "$GITLAB_USER_NAME (gitlab pipeline)"

# set the remote URL with authentication
# if using a personal access token, 
# you will need to replace `gitlab-ci-token` with your username
git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:${PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git"

# Uncomment these steps if you have an error for not being on a branch
# git fetch origin
# git checkout "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"


# create a commit and push it to the commit branch
git commit --allow-empty -m "my release commit"
git push origin "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"

# create a tag and push the tag
git tag "my-realease-tag"
git push origin "my-release-tag"
```

Comment: I was hoping to expand on my question, but I did exactly that. I set both the user email and the user name. My question is really, how do I push back to the repo? What URL? the job token? When I did that, I got an error telling me I cant push to this repo.

Comment: @Pezetter well, that sounds like a completely different question than the one you asked. And I'm not sure what error you mean, so it may be hard for me to understand why you're having an error if I don't know what the error message says. But in any case, I edited the answer to include a complete example using a project access token. You can't use a job token to push to the repo -- you'll need a project token, group token, personal access token, or a deploy key. Hope that helps.

Comment: I disagree. My question is clear. "I would like to be able to push that commit and tag to the current commit branch, and the push should be "by the user".

Is there any way to accomplish this? "

Your original response told me how to set a user, not how to push a commit on the current branch. 

The second part was "I dont want to use a token, because that loses the user." Given your modified response, I'm going to assume it's just not possible. Seems strange that a manual job, by a user, doesnt carry the users privileges.

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I misunderstood @Pezetter -- When you said "I dont want to use a token, because that loses the user." I understood this to mean that you already knew how to push to the branch, but just didn't like that the result was that the commit author was not your user account. However, it _is_ possible to push as your user with a token. I'm not sure I understand what result you're expecting or why you think it's not possible... From my perspective, I showed you exactly how to do it!